# C++ cin.ignore To ignore spaces, numbers, and characters to test a palindrome

Tags: c++, palindrome

I need to process a user input to see if it is a palindrome. Our professor said to use cin.ignore() to ignore spaces, numbers, and other characters so we will just compare the letter inputs.

So far I have just found code that ignores just one of these at a time and the code is more advanced than my learning so I do not know how to modify or apply it to my code.

I have the code to check the palindrome, I just do not know how to make it ignore the unwanted inputs.

Sorry this sort of question has been asked many times over but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

```
do
{
    checkInput = false;

    cout << "Enter the Palindrome: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    len = input.length();

    if (len == 0)
    {
        cout << "\nNo data was entered, please enter a palindrome.\n";
        checkInput = false;
    }

} while (checkInput);

for (int i = 0, j = input.size() - 1; i < input.size(); i++, j--)
{

    if (input[i] != input[j] && input[i] + 32 != input[j] && input[i] - 32 != input[j])
    {

        isPalindrome = false;
        break;

    }
}

if (isPalindrome)
{
    cout << "This is a Palindrome!!" << endl;
}

else
{
    cout << "This is not a Palindrome." << endl;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is your code that almost works but doesn't quite?

Comment: The code I have just tests palindromes if they are written out precisely by user input.

Comment: Most of what I have found provides a specific solution to the person asking that dodges the need to get rid of the characters or presents an error. Neither of which apply to or help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im assuming that input is a string. if so then what we want to do before your for loop is have another for loop to run through the string and remove anything unwanted from the string. I am going to assume that all you want to deal with are the upper and lowercase letters, as we are focusing on the ascii values between 65-90 and 97-122. source http://www.ascii-code.com/

to so do we can simply check each index in the string to see if it falls between these two ranges, and if it doesn't, then delete it.

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<input.size();i++)
    {
      if(input[i]< 65 || (90 <input[i] && input[i] < 97) || input[i] > 122)   
      {
        input.erase(i,1);
        i--
      }
    }
```

that should work.

Comment: I just posted it in my original comment, my code just tests for the palindrome. I have been trying to figure out how to use pointers or some other way of going through everything and getting rid of unwanted characters but my book doesn't cover it.

Comment: @Bowski this should help you now, if it doesn't work let me know what errors you get and ill see if i can fix it.

Comment: It is all working well so far. Thank you so much, I knew it was some easy code like that I just for some reason was trying to use cin.ignore() or some way to do it with pointers. Thanks again!